# RestSharp is crashing with Unity3d when running on iPhone

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, mono, restsharp

I'm trying to attach RestSharp to Unity3d. 
Original RestSharp mono lib works fine in Editor, but on device its crashing with callstack

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
Parameter name: options
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection.GetEnumerator () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.validate_options (RegexOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex..ctor (System.String pattern, RegexOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at RestSharp.RestClient..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at RestSharp.RestClient..ctor (System.String baseUrl) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

That means, exception appears inside of ctor RestClient(string), which is a wrapper around default ctor. And inside of default ctor, there is

```
public RestClient()
    {
#if WINDOWS_PHONE
        this.UseSynchronizationContext = true;
#endif
        this.ContentHandlers = new Dictionary<string, IDeserializer>();
        this.AcceptTypes = new List<string>();
        this.DefaultParameters = new List<Parameter>();

        // register default handlers
        this.AddHandler("application/json", new JsonDeserializer());
        this.AddHandler("application/xml", new XmlDeserializer());
        this.AddHandler("text/json", new JsonDeserializer());
        this.AddHandler("text/x-json", new JsonDeserializer());
        this.AddHandler("text/javascript", new JsonDeserializer());
        this.AddHandler("text/xml", new XmlDeserializer());
        this.AddHandler("*+json", new JsonDeserializer());
        this.AddHandler("*+xml", new XmlDeserializer());
        this.AddHandler("*", new XmlDeserializer());

        this.FollowRedirects = true;
    }
```

At this point, i dont see where next step with Regex ctor appears. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have encountered the same issue while building a standalone Windows project with Unity 5.2.1. In the editor it all works fine, until you create a build.

I believe the problem has something to do with the 'structuredSyntaxSuffixWildcardRegex' used in the 'AddHandler' method. While I don't know exactly why it fails, I do know a previous version of RestSharp does work for us.

I guess you're also using the latest RestSharp version, so could you give [RestSharp v105.1.0](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/releases/tag/105.1.0) a try?

It seemed to stop functioning from Restshap v105.2.1, I am going through the commits to see a possible culprit. I will fork and fix it if I have found a solution.

Also I must inform you that in our case GZIP decompression also wasn't working due to missing Mono.Posix libraries. This problem occurred when the server returned a gzipped response and the RestClient allowed it. We had to work around that by using 'Fabman08's fix which made [decompression configurable](https://github.com/Fabman08/RestSharp/commit/85c20480bc08b17d6db6d8f30df84984b2d4aaeb).

Comment: Hi, thanks for a hint. I cant try it now, as i'm busy with another project, but if you have similar problem - please, keep me posted, if you got an issue solved for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have forked the RestSharp repository in an attempt to fix the above and other Unity related issues. It's located at: https://github.com/eamonwoortman/RestSharp.Unity.

Your and other issues have already been fixed and were tested against a 64bit standalone Windows build.

Could you verify if these fixes also work on your iOS project? Make sure you build the RestSharp.Net35.Unity project.